# field width while using delayed expansion

Tags: batch-file, formatting, dos

I am using a for loop and constructing names of env variables ( like abc%%i , where i is the loop variable )  that are to be read , and use delayed expansion to print out their values (assuming these env variables have already been set ) ..

echo is dos provides the facility to mention the field width of the variable to be printed out like echo %x:~-8% will right justify the value of x and the field width will be 8 ..

But since i am using delayed expansion , !abc%%i:~-8! does not seem to be working .

Any ideas as to how to set field width while using delayed expansion ,??

Happiness
Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know who told you that `%x:~-8%` would pad out your variable but they're wrong, at least in the version of `cmd` that I'm using (XP).

That construct will simply give tou the last 8 characters if the variable is 8 or more. If it's less than 8, you'll get the variable itself, sans padding.

If you want it padded, you can use something like:

```
set y=        %x%
echo %y:~-8%
```

And, as can be seen from this script, `!abc%%i:~-8!` works just fine once you realise that you're responsible for the padding:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('echo 1 ^&^& echo 92') do (
    set var%%i=        %%i
    echo !var%%i:~-8!
)
echo.=====
set var
endlocal
```

This outputs:

```
       1
      92
=====
var1=       1
var92=       92
```

as you would expect.

Comment: Thanx for ur insightful answer . I misinterpreted the construct . this is fine . But i would like to know whether there is any method using which i can left justify my output and set the field width . Right now i am using an exe file ( C++ ) that would do this for me (Thanx to stroustrup) . But this method seems to be inelegant , please do enlighten me me if there is any way to make it and "All-script" affair !

Comment: Yes, ask another question :-) Basically, it boils down to : `set x=hello`, `set y=%x%<10 spaces go here>`, `echo %y:~1,10% (or something like that, I might have the numbers slightly off). In other words, add ten spaces to the end to ensure it's at least long enough then use your current method to get the first 10 characters - left-justification done. Same as right-just except that one adds spaces at the front, not the back.

Comment: @Deepak Choosing "Accept" to the answer that helped you would make you more elegant ;-)